# Yii set language to directory protected/messages in components from config but not work

Tags: yii, lan

I have Yii project and change my language in config/main.php to fa_ir, and set components basePath = protected/messages but don't changed basePath, yet is selected fa_ir from framework directory !!!

my project main.php code :

return.array(

```
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'New web site',
    'defaultController'=>'site',
    //'timezone'=>'Asia/Tehran',
    'language'=>'fa_ir',

// preloading 'log' component
'preload'=>array('log'),

// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
            'application.extensions.*',
),

'modules'=>array(
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'123',
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),


),

// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,                        
    ),

            'messages'=>array(
                'basePath'=>Yiibase::getPathOfAlias('application.messages'),
            ),
    // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

    'urlManager'=>array(
                        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                        'showScriptName'=>false,
                        'caseSensitive'=>false,
                        'rules'=>array(

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',                            
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

        ),
    ),
```

and ...

So directory files is : protect/message/fa_ir/yii.php  and zii.php

I am very grateful from respondents.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a single language:

```
'language'=>'fa',
```

Or:

```
'language'=>'ir',
```

And use the same for your directory.